# Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver

Tags: java, postgresql, jboss

Boa noite a todos.

Estou com um problema, que acredito ser simples de resolver.

na IDE(netbeans) o projeto roda tranquilo, porem quando publico no jbossacontece o seguinte erro:

> 18:54:40,111 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class org.postgresql.Driver (version 9.3)
>   18:54:40,154 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS018210: Registering web context: /PrjX
>   18:54:40,173 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS018559: Deployed "PrjX_V2.war"

CODIGO DE CONEXÃO AO BANCO:

```
public Connection conexaoPostgres(){
Connection con = null;
try {
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://[IP]:[PORTA]/[BASE_DE_DADOS]","[LOG]","[PASS]");
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    System.out.println("Projeto PrjX, classe Dao, método conexaoPostgres, erro: "+e.getMessage());
}
return con;
```

}

nunca usei postgree com java, não faço ideia do q possa ser, acho muito estranho funcionar no netbeans pelo glassfish e no jboss não.

versão do driver postgree: postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc41.jar

alguem ja passou por isso????

Answer (score 0):

Talvez o driver que esta configurado no jboss não é compatível. 
Verifique se o driver que esta configurado  no container(jboss) é o mesmo que esta sendo usado no netbeans.